# HTML5 + Javascript audio trigger events at certain times in audio playback

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

I am researching setting up a script that will show certain notes along with accompanying music tracks. Basically I need certain times in the audio track to trigger events. I have seen I could use the currentTime similar to the following, but I am getting hung up on a good way to make a concise function to move between frames and move back and firth if there is a rewind etc. Help's appreciated greatly!

```
$("#ogg_player_1_obj").bind('timeupdate', notePosition);

function notePosition(){
    myVid=document.getElementById("ogg_player_1_obj");
    mct=myVid.currentTime;

    //SET Frame based on time???

}
```

Comment: what do you want to do in notePosition()? Seems to me you answered the question in the title. Just a few if statements and you are done.

Comment: i need to show a certain frame that corresponds to a certain time

Comment: Have you looked at using popcorn.js? http://popcornjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
function notePosition(){
//your code.
if(frame1start <= mct && frame1end >= mct) {
    $(".frame").fadeOut(100);
    $("#frame1").fadeIn(100);
}
//and again for every frame.
}
```

This works if you put every frame in a seperate element with class frame and the id frame + number.